# where does "sudo apt-get install <package_name>" get the packages?

Tags: apt, package-management

I started using terminal on Ubuntu and one of the first commands I've learned has been `sudo apt-get install`. However, I still have a doubt about this command. Where does it take the packages needed to install the program? Are they already present on the computer? And, in this case, where? Or does it download them from the internet at the moment I send the command?

Comment: It downloads them from the internet.

Comment: Thank you Pilot6, and in this case, how does it know where to get them? I'll explain to you my doubt with an example.  Let's suppose I want to install both w3m and google chrome. If I run the command **sudo apt-get install w3m** it understands where to get the package, it gets it and unpacks it.  However, if I type **sudo apt-get install google-chrome**, it wouldn't do that. Instead, in this case, I should go searching on the internet the package on my own, and then unpack it. How does the computer know which packages he can find on his own, and how can I know which ones are them?

Comment: When you install Chrome the first time, it will add a link where look for upgrades.

Comment: I managed to understand how does it work thanks to your answer. My doubt was how does it know which packages it can install on his own, and how does it know where to pick them on the internet. Now I understood it manages to do that thanks to a file installed along with ubuntu, which contains all these pieces of information.
Thank you! 
(The story with google-chrome was just an example!!! Thank you so much!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Packages come from repositories

Canonical, the maker of Ubuntu maintains repositories in the internet. The information about the location of the repositories are installed along with Ubuntu in a list.

There are other repositories maintained by other people. You can add those to the list if you need to install some special packages.

`apt-get install` will go through all the repositories in the list and find the the lastest version and download and install it. This process will also find and download and install any other packages the first package depends on.

The repository for `Google-chrome` is not included in the default. That's why `apt-get` does not work. Once you download and install the Deb file, the installation process adds the Google repository to the list. After that `apt-get upgrade` will find the lastest version of chrome.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/apt/sources.list`

In this file you can see the sources where the system looks for packages. You can add other sources for new packages that aren't listed

`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: ...and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`